# EF ignoring fluent API for ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDetails>()
          .HasRequired(c => c.Product)
          .WithMany()
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

However when I check the table definition generated I see:

```
 CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ProductDetails_dbo.Product_ProductId] FOREIGN KEY ([ProductId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Product] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

What am I missing? why does it create the `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: I will update code but ProductOptions and ProductDetails have the same constraints, thanks for the catch. Code updated.

Comment: After changing configuration had you migrated the database? If so what was the migration code that you executed on the database?

Comment: Yes I run the Update-Database

Comment: I can see a little conflict here, the `Product` is required, so if cascading is disabled, the `ProductId` cannot become `NULL`, it should be deleted any way instead (meaning cascading should be applied). You can try using `HasOptional(c => c.Product)` instead.

Comment: @Hopeless Good suggestion. But the idea was that I take care of the deletes "manually". Moreover why doesn't EF complain or throw an error?

Comment: @Hopeless I tried HasOptional, it didn't help, the constraint is still generated.

Comment: it's hard to see what's wrong, as the final debugging step, I would try creating a new project using the similar configuration code to see if it has the same behavior, if it does not then you know there must something wrong right in your current project, otherwise I have no idea.

Comment: @Hopeless I reversed the definition and it all worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an issue with EF in the syntax above.
When I reverse the definition like described below, it works:

```
  modelBuilder
         .Entity<Product>()
         .HasMany(p => p.Details)
         .WithRequired()
         .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```